# Super Beginner JavaScript....What am I doing wrong please?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple calculator however I am having validation issues. Can someone please explain why the first if statement passes but then when I enter an answer for the second prompt it jumps back to the first if statement as if it did not pass in the first place?

Here is my code so far...http://jsfiddle.net/kiradale/03nLz9bh/

```
var userNumbers = prompt("Enter only two numbers.").split(" "); 
var a = userNumbers[0];
var b = userNumbers[1];

var userOperator = prompt("Enter a multiplication, division, addition, or subtraction operator.");

if (userNumbers == '' || isNaN(userNumbers)){

    alert("Hey! Enter only two numbers and no blanks!");
}

if  (userOperator === "*" || userOperator === "/" || userOperator === "+" || userOperator === "-"){

    var myCalculator = function(a,b){

        alert("okay ready to go"); 
    }

    myCalculator(); 
}

else {
        alert("Hey! Enter only the specified operators and no blanks!");
}
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `userNumbers` is an array, not a string or a number.

Comment: @Nit is right, on the first if statement you need to check a & b vars not userNumbers directly.

Comment: check whether a and b are numbers instead of userNumbers

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
var userNumbers = prompt("Enter only two numbers.").split(" "); 
var a = parseInt(userNumbers[0]);
var b = parseInt(userNumbers[1]);
var userOperator = prompt("Enter a multiplication, division, addition, or subtraction operator.");

if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)){

    alert("Hey! Enter only two numbers and no blanks!");
}

else if (userOperator === "*" || userOperator === "/" || userOperator === "+" || userOperator === "-"){

    var myCalculator = function(a,b){

        alert("okay ready to go"); 
    }
    myCalculator(); 
}

else {
        alert("Hey! Enter only the specified operators and no blanks!");
}
```

You have to just check whether a and b are number or not. Since the userNumber is an array of string you have to parse it to integer format and then check for it

Answer (score 0):

`userNumbers` should be an array with two elements - but you're checking if it's not a number. isNaN(userNumbers) will return true, so you will always get this alert:

```
(userNumbers == '' || isNaN(userNumbers))
```

Rather - you should check is it's an array, and if its length is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Because the validation of the number input is executed after you've prompted for both the numbers and the operator. After both prompts have finished you check if `userNumbers` is an empty string or if `isNaN(usernumbers)` returns `true`, which it will for my input "2 2" since that is not a number.